# How to select Excel table rows as we search in SQL Oracle database?

Tags: sql, excel, office365

Consider you have a Excel table which stores data columns names and types: ColumnA (varchar2), ColumnB(date), ColumnC(varchar2).

I want to save some rows in a new Excel Sheet which is same result as I would run a SQL statement in Oracle database in order to group by ColumnA and max value of ColumB. So, rows result will be like below SQL statement:

```
select ColumnA, max(ColumnB)
from MyExcelSheet
group by ColumnA, ColumnB
```

How to have such result in a new Excel sheet or file?

Comment: Create a pivot table and put Column A and B on rows. then put the max of Column B on values...

Comment: Issue is that I need data like I'd have in SQL query, not summarized like Pivot tables do. Reason is to copy/paste into a new Excel sheet.

Answer (score -1):

Pivot Table, or use Google Sheets' `QUERY` function.

Comment: Google Sheets Query looks great for it. Actually I resolved it by Google sheets query, but I will have a look on Excel Power query